# Transloco - Is there a way to reference other translations within a plural rule?

Tags: transloco

We are using plural rules in the JSON in our app, such as:

```
"myPluralRule": "{myCount, plural, =0 {no results} one {1 result} other {# results}}"
```

However, we need to translate these into 27 other languages and, although we've tried to explain precisely, the translators are having difficulty understanding what to do. Is it possible to make the sections within the inner curly brackets into separately referenced translations? Something like:

```
"myPluralRule": "{myCount, plural, =0 {@no_results} one {@one_result} other {@#_results}}",
"@no_results": "No results",
"@one_result": "1 result",
"@#_results": "# results",
```

This would make it easier for the translators and make it possible for us to automate the preparation of the strings for translation.